# Why the code in react was working, but few weeks later it has error? TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

Last week my code was working as below:

```
function UserCard({ user }) {
    const { name, birthday, _id, url, area } = user

    //.........
    //.........
    //.........

    return (
        <div>
            <img src={url.replace('upload/', 'upload/w_300,h_300,c_limit/')} className="UserCard-img" alt="user-img" />

            <h3>{name.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1).toLowerCase()}</h3>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But today I found the website had error, it said:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')

And then I remove 'slice' and 'replace', then it's working now.
These kind of things happened twice already, why the code is unstable? I shouldn't write function inside {}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that `name` has an `undefined` value.  So whatever is using this component isn't (or at least isn't always) providing a value for the `name` prop.

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to only try to de-reference the value if one exists:

```
name?.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase()
```

Or perhaps not display the element at all if there is no value to display:

```
{ name ?
  <h3>{name.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1).toLowerCase()}</h3> :
  null
}
```

There are a variety of ways to structure the logic, but overall the point is to check if the variable has a value before trying to use it.